# Django TemplateDoesNotExist - can not render the template

Tags: django

I am new to django and I am using version 4.1.2. I have created an app with the following structure

[image]

I have configured the app ( 'home') template in the primary setting file like the following. but still, I am getting the error

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR/'home', 'templates'),
            ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

here is my view code

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

# Create your views here.

def home(request):
    return render(request, ' home/welcome.html' , {})
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove the space in the template path: `' home/welcome.html'` have to be `'home/welcome.html'`